# Custom maven plugin: install and execute the plugin in one build

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I wrote a custom maven plugin that scaffolds java-code from a custom schema.

The project-structure is like this:

```
Project
+ plugin
+ web-application
```

The reactor compiles first the plugin, then the application.

The usual mvn-command is:

```
mvn
```

... who is triggering the `<defaultGoal>plugin:scaffold package</defaultGoal>`

On fresh machines the build fails because the plugin is not yet known at the time the reactor plan the build-phases. So I have to call `mvn install` first. Then `mvn plugin:scaffold package` works like a charm.

The problem is: Whenever I modify the scaffolder-plugin and call `mvn plugin:scaffold package` the modifications of the scaffolder-plugin is not yet used because it is not yet installed into the repository. So I have to call `mvn install` first again.

Is there a way to:

1. Install the modification to the plugin
2. Build the webapplication using the modifications of the plugin

in one step?

Comment: The `install` phase contains the `package` phase. You you really need the `install` phase before running your plugin or is `compile` sufficient? If it is, you can use `mvn compile plugin:scaffold package` or define your phase to require the `compile` phase.

Comment: not sure if understand this correctly, but couldn't you simply execute `mvn plugin:scaffold package -U` where the `-U` flag updates dependencies

Answer (score 5):

First your plugin must be a module of the root project for the resolution to work correctly:

```
<modules>
    <module>plugin</module>
    <module>app</module>
</modules>
```

Then declare the plugin in the `build/plugins` section your application pom

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.example.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>sayhi</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>sayhi</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The first time you run the plugin or when the plugin changes you need to run at least the `package` phase so the plugin jar is created. It must be run from the root project:

```
mvn package
```

The plugin will be executed during the `generate-sources` phase:

```
[INFO] --- plugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT:sayhi (sayhi) @ app ---
[INFO] Hello, world.
[INFO]
```

When you change the plugin just run (again from root project):

```
mvn package
```

and you will see the changes:

```
[INFO] --- plugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT:sayhi (sayhi) @ app ---
[INFO] Hello, worldxxxx.
[INFO]
```

See a full example on [Github](https://github.com/frant-hartm/maven-plugin-example)

Comment: "The first time you run the plugin or when the plugin changes" you are telling a two-step-workflow. But I need to do this "*in one step*"!!!

Comment: What do you mean by two step? All you need is `mvn package` (or with clean if you e.g. rename classes).

Comment: I have changed the wording a bit, hope it's clear now that you should run single `mvn package` command

Comment: I checked-out your project and your projects works as expected. But if you move `<build>` from `/app/pom.xml` to `/pom.xml` you can not compile without having the plugin installed into the local `.m2`-repository. Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, it won't work. If you have multiple web-app like modules (which is why I imagine you want to put the build to parent pom, otherwise it doesn't make sense) you could either put whole configuration into `pluginManagement` and refer to the plugin just by name in the web-app pom build part, or you can create a module in-between root and web-app module(s).

Comment: You have the point. A module in-between might do the trick, thanks. Let me come to you back later :)

Comment: Did not yet checked it. Have trouble to argue that we need to change the structure.